# One server serves over multiple IPs

Tags: networking, ftp, mysql, svn

I am a software developer who happened to buy a dedicated server and 3 additional IPs to host 3 websites. Let's say the main IP is 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 to 1.1.1.4 for 3 websites.

What I have managed to do so far:

- 1 nginx instance that serves 3 website
- 1 svn accessible over 1.1.1.2 to 1.1.1.4 for 3 "teams".

Now I am setting up mysql and ftp, but it only accessible over 1.1.1.1 or localhost.

What do I need to do? For svn, I just start it and go. For nginx, I just specify the IP in some config file.

Please help

Comment: For MySQL, see the answers to [MySQL: Bind to more than one IP address?](http://serverfault.com/questions/139323/mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address) at Server Fault, which is a sister site to this one. For FTP, what FTP server software are you using? What operating system are you using? If Linux, which version, e.g., CentOS, Ubuntu, etc.?

Comment: @moonpoint : thank you. I am working on that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also don't necessarily need extra IP's to host more sites.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773544/nginx-different-domains-on-same-ip